# Cannot set new parent window in read only excel workbook

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I have an excel workbook with a userform to facilitate data entry. I made the userform a child of the active window using SetParent in order to keep it bound to the workbook.

The problem is that I cannot get the ActiveWindow handle when the workbook is opened in read-only mode, as is the case when opening it from sharepoint.

Is there a workaround for this?

I get the handle with 
`FindWindowEx(DeskHWnd, 0&, "EXCEL7", ActiveWindow.Caption)`

Comment: How are you getting the handle currently? Also, do you mean read-only mode or Protected mode?

Comment: I modified my question. How do I know if it is protected mode or read-only. When opening the file from Sharepoint the yellow bar under the ribbon reads "read-only".

Comment: Do you see anything about "Protected mode" in the window caption?